# How to use ShuffleDriverComponents to initiate service for shuffling

Tags: apache-spark, spark-shuffle

ShuffleDriverComponents description says:
"This method should prepare the module with its shuffle components i.e. registering against
an external file servers or shuffle services, or creating tables in a shuffle
storage data database."

I'm preparing a shuffle service for writing data to the disk.
This shuffle service need to be opened once with all of his resources to be used by Shuffle Executers when they perform writes.
I thought to use the initializeApplication of ShuffleDriverComponents to initialize my service, but I'm not sure how the executers will be able to access my service and my service methods.